# Authorize.net Multiple refund/void options for same transaction?

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am using Authorize.net API in my PHP project for Payments. Recently I integrated the
[REFUND/VOID](http://www.authorize.net/support/merchant/Submitting_Transactions/Credit_Card_Transaction_Types.htm) Transactions programmatic, Its working fine but now I want refund the amount multiple times is it possible ?.

Example: A User paid $100 (Product price $80 + shipping price $20) to purchase a product in my website. Now First I want to refund $20, then later I want to refund $80 for the same transaction. Every thing need to using the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple refunds can only be processed once the transaction is settled. It sounds like since the transaction was not yet settled, your API call voided the original transaction completely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do two refunds for the original transaction. In fact, it's no different then doing one other then the fact that you are doing a second, or possibly third, transaction. Just run your second refund just like the first for the specified amount.

Comment: yes i tried.. I paid 3$ and voided $1 in first attempt It works well. In second attempt I tried to void $2.. Its shows response code as 1 (SUCCESS) and message as Already the transaction has voided